# Any way to ensure that Change Data Capture clean up process does not delete the change data that you haven't processed yet?

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture, archive

I'm using CDC feature to track changes that are being made, since the cleanup period is set to 3 days by default, I have to run jobs to archive this change data from the CDC system tables to my tables. However, there's a probability that CDC might delete a few change data records that I haven't been able to archive yet.

For instance, if i set the retention period to 10 minutes and run the cleanup job after 10 minutes, only the data that has been archived should be deleted, and the data that hasn't been archived should be left untouched.
Is there a way around this predicament?

Comment: Can't you make sure that you always archive and empty well before (and I'm talking at least hours) the retention period expires?

Comment: Yea, that is one option, but if something goes wrong and you're unable to archive it, I want to be sure that I won't lose the unprocessed data

Comment: How long could something be wrong before you or clients would notice? Make the expiry time twice that.

Comment: Yes...you could disable the job and roll your own.  But no, if you want to use what is created when you enable CDC.